# scrapy xpath selector works in browser, but not in crawl or shell

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm crawling the following page: http://www.worldfootball.net/all_matches/eng-premier-league-2015-2016/

The first parse goes through and should get all the links with scores as the text. I first loop through all the match rows:

```
for sel in response.xpath('(//table[@class="standard_tabelle"])[1]/tr'):
```

And then get the links in the 6th column of the table

```
    matchHref = sel.xpath('.//td[6]/a/@href').extract()
```

This however returns nothing. I tried the same selector in Chrome (with the addition of 'tbody' between table and tr selector) though and I get results. But, if I try the same selector (without the tbody) in scrapy shell, I only get results from the first response.xpath, while nothing with the following link extraction.

I've done a handful of these loops before but this simple thing has me stumped. Is there a better way to debug this? Here is some shell output where I just try and simplify my second selection to just select any td

```
In [36]: for sel in response.xpath('(//table[@class="standard_tabelle"])[1]/tr'):
   ....:     sel.xpath('.//td')
   ....:
```

Nothing. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is to use the fact that these links in the 6th column contain the `report` in the `href` attribute value. Demo from the shell:

```
$ scrapy shell "http://www.worldfootball.net/all_matches/eng-premier-league-2015-2016/"
>>> for row in response.xpath('(//table[@class="standard_tabelle"])[1]/tr[not(th)]'):
...     print(row.xpath(".//a[contains(@href, 'report')]/@href").extract_first())
... 
/report/premier-league-2015-2016-manchester-united-tottenham-hotspur/
/report/premier-league-2015-2016-afc-bournemouth-aston-villa/
/report/premier-league-2015-2016-everton-fc-watford-fc/
...
/report/premier-league-2015-2016-stoke-city-west-ham-united/
/report/premier-league-2015-2016-swansea-city-manchester-city/
/report/premier-league-2015-2016-watford-fc-sunderland-afc/
/report/premier-league-2015-2016-west-bromwich-albion-liverpool-fc/
```

Also note this part: `tr[not(th)]` - this helps to skip header rows with no relevant links.

Comment: That is brilliant. And I have noted the not(th) selector! From looking at scrapy's documentation I didn't know selectors like that were possible. I had written something like this before to get around those th's: ``thRow = sel.xpath('./th') if thRow: return`` Thank you very much

Comment: Why is it though, if I do the first selector ``response.xpath`` without the ``print``, the shell shows results. But with the second selector inside the ``for`` loop that it only prints results with the ''print'' before it?

Comment: @willdanceforfun not exactly sure what are you describing, could you elaborate (may be in a separate question if it makes sense..)? Thank you.

Comment: I've popped the question over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790211/why-this-inconsistent-behaviour-using-scrapy-shell-printing-results